# How to fire both client side and server side click events of button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

For a requirement, I need to fire both client side and server side click events of a button in  ASP.NET. Is that possible? I have tried like the below. But it does not fire client side click event.

[ASPX]

```
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Disable" OnClick="disable"  CausesValidation="false"  OnClientClick="return click();" />
```

[Script]

```
 function click()
 {
        alert("hi")

  }
```

Comment: your code seems ok it should work. Can you tell the behavior you are getting after button clicked.

Comment: It fires Server side click event. But not client side event.

Comment: All events are client side. There's no such thing as a server-side event. ASP's syntax just makes it appear that way. One of the many reasons, I avoid ASP.

Comment: Yes. The error is in my code!. I specified client-side event as 'click();' . That's the mistake i had done. Thanks for your much help anyways :). I feel like silly now!!

Comment: I have renamed the client-side click event as 'disable()' and it works now. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it's possible. If the client side Javascript returns `true` then the server-side method will get called.

For example:

```
function click()
{
    return confirm("Do you want to continue?");
}
```

Comment: For me server-side event gets called without firing the client-side event. I am stuck over there.

Comment: Sounds like a Javascript error then - check the Javascript code is valid.

Comment: Yes. The error is in my code!. I specified client-side event as  'click();' . That's the mistake i had done. Thanks for your much help anyways :). I feel like silly now!!.

Comment: Glad you've got it sorted. We all need help from time to time! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Disable" OnClick="disable"  CausesValidation="false"  OnClientClick="click();" />

function click()
{
   alert("hi");
   this.click();

}
```

Comment: Will `this.click()` not just call the `OnClientClick` again? Either way, this isn't how it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

The client side function must be called in your code. Only thing is depending on what it returns the server side function will get called:

```
   function Click() {
    alert('Hi');
    if (somecondition) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also check your server side event handler if it is named correct as you mention in your code "disable". I think this isnt proper name.

Also check if you really need CausesValidation attribute? as this would have been for your validater which might no longer needed as client side function is manually called.